# How to do a camera movement in spriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have created a `SKSpriteNode` for a camera with a physic body size of 0.0 , to avoid unwanted collisions and a world node:

```
    -(void)createSceneContents {

SKNode *world = [SKNode node];
world.name = @"world";
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.1, 0);
SKSpriteNode *camera = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];
camera.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
camera.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
camera.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = NO;
camera.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = noColisions;
camera.alpha = 0.5;
camera.zPosition = 1;
camera.name = @"cam";
[self addChild:world];
[world addChild:camera];
```

I've tried a little tutorial to add a camera in a spriteKit platform game, but i can't even move the view, i don't know hoy to access to the property that move the view. Anybody knows what am i doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    //I've tried with @"cam" and @"hero"
    [self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName:@"world"]];
}
-(void)centerOnNode:(SKNode *) camera {
    CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [camera.scene convertPoint:camera.position fromNode:camera.parent];

    [self.parent setPosition:CGPointMake(
        camera.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x,
        camera.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y
    )];
}
```

Comment: Apple have implemented something of the sort in the 'Adventure' sample  sprite kit project... You can look up how they did it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the example from [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html), which you are following the camera node isn't an SKSprite, it's an **SKNode**. I think that will fix your problem.

To answer the question from the title, what you're essentially doing is attaching a world node to the scene. Inside this node, all the sprites are placed. As a child to the world node you add another node for the camera.

This gives you three distinct coordinate systems. Imagine, three sheets of paper, the bottom most one is your world, ie the layer with all the sprites. On top of that is a small piece of paper that represents the camera. Above all of this you have a transparent box that represents your viewing area.

The way it's set up it's impossible to move the top most transparent viewing layer. Instead, what you're doing is moving the point that's sits on top of the world layer and then sliding the world layer to that point.

Now imagine, in the paper scenario, this is a 2D scrolling world where you can only go left and right. Now take the camera point and put it all the way to the right most side of the viewing area. Now, take the world layer and drag it to the left until the camera is in the center of the non-moveable viewing area. That is more or less, what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

In Apple's Adventure sample game they don't move the camera but the "World" SKNode which is the top one.

Excerpt from Apple docs on how they do it:

> In Adventure all world-related nodes, including background tiles,
>   characters, and foliage, are children of a world node, which in turn
>   is a child of the scene. We change the position of this top-of-tree
>   world node within the scene to give the effect of moving a camera
>   across the level. By contrast, the nodes that make up the HUD are
>   children of a separate node that is a direct child of the scene rather
>   than of the world node, so that the elements in the HUD don’t move
>   when we “move the camera.”

[Read about it more here](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/KeepingUptoDate/KeepingUptoDate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH9-SW4)

Answer (score 2):

to add the previous answers , you should center on your camera , not the world..

so instead of

```
[self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName:@"world"]];
```

you should use

```
[self centerOnNode: [self childNodeWithName:@"cam"]];
```

and dont forget to change your camera to SKNode instead of SKSprite.

.. and for testing, add a moveTo action on your camera node , move it around back and forth to check if your camera centering works. I recommend putting the call in the touchesbegan

example (put this on your scene where your camera is) :

Put these before the @implementation

```
@interface yourClassNameHere()  // edit this to your own class name
@property SKNode *theWorld;
@property SKNode *theCamera;
@property BOOL cameraRunning;
@end
```

As you see above, i put the nodes (world and camera) on property of this class, so i dont refer them with node name like you did on your post..

Put this on the Implementation section

```
// Process Camera centering

-(void) didSimulatePhysics {
    [self centerOnNode:self.theCamera];
}

-(void) centerOnNode: (SKNode *) node {
    CGPoint pos = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    CGPoint p = node.parent.position;
    node.parent.position = CGPointMake(p.x - pos.x, p.y-pos.y);   
}

// .. Move the camera around when you touch , to see if it works.. 

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (!self.cameraRunning) {
    self.cameraRunning = YES;
    SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:500 duration:3];
    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-500 duration:3];
    SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveByX:-500 y:0 duration:3];
    SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveByX:500 y:0 duration:3];
    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, moveRight,moveDown,moveLeft]];
    [self.theCamera runAction:sequence];

} else {
        self.cameraRunning = NO;
        [self.theCamera removeAllActions];
        self.theCamera.position = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```

regards

PS: do you want anchor point 0,0 or 1,1 ? check your anchor point setting there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the view, just move the camera:

```
// Center the view at 100, 0
camera.position = CGPointMake(100, 0);
```

Here's a slightly longer example here on [how to set up a 2D camera system in SpriteKit](http://swiftalicio.us/?p=20) (in Swift, not ObjC, but easily translated).